# Is there a website/game builds a sentence for the given word?

Tags: sentence

I just got a request from someone the request is for a website/game which you gave it a word it builds you the sentence. I know it might not be a good way to learn but maybe for a while or for some instant usage. I looked up Google but nothing helped.

Comment: Funny you mention Google, because if you type any word into Google, it will build you hundreds of thousands of sentences using that word. What else do you need?

Comment: @RegDwighт come on that's not an effective way and you don't get a fully well structured sentences you only get some predictions of you search.....hope you be more helpful next time!!!!!

Comment: How is searching existing sentences produced by actual people not an effective way? How is creating random sentences from scratch better? Not only is that "not a good way to learn", it's the worst way to learn. Producing a syntactically valid sentence is trivial (you give me a noun, I return "I eat [noun]", there's your sentence), while producing semantically valid sentences is an unsurmountable challenge ("I eat mountain" is obviously nonsense). You might also note that this question has been closed as a duplicate of another one that *has answers*. Hope you are more attentive next time.